# How to make wordpress safe from sql injection

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How to make below code safe from sql injection.

PHP Code

```
 global $wpdb;

    if($wpdb->insert(
            'votes',
            array(
                    'votes' => $votes,
                    'competition' => $competition,
                    'uid' => $uid


                )
    ) == false) wp_die('Database Insertion failed'); else echo 'Database insertion successful<p />';
```

Comment: use the [prepared statement](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) api provided from the codex

Comment: ok thanks is prepared statement mandatory for all kind of queries like insert, select, update and delete in wordpress. Because I have read somewhere that we can go without it incase of maybe insert query.

Comment: @Ghost Bummer, `insert()` actually calls `prepare()` but values are escaped using `mysql(i)_real_escape_string()`, no real prepared statements in WordPress.

Comment: @jeroen yeah, most of these wrapper classes emulates prepared statements and does not really send the query separate the bound vars and the statement, but yeah thats what they have, might as well use PDO and take off prepared emulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wordpress insert and update statements used prepare statement internally so no need to use them from outside.
assuming $votes integer and other variables as string

global $wpdb;

```
if($wpdb->insert(
        'votes',
        array(
                'votes' => $votes,
                'competition' => $competition,
                'uid' => $uid
                 ),
        array(
              '%d',
              '%s',
              '%s',
            )
) == false) wp_die('Database Insertion failed'); else echo 'Database insertion successful<p />';
```

Comment: That sounds very logical but do you have any references to for example the codex that confirm that?

Comment: http://codepeach.com/wordpress/wordpress-database-interaction-wpdb/ The insert() method returns false if it failed to insert the row, but if successful it will store the AUTO_INCREMENT ID of the newly inserted row in $wpdb->insert_id. There is no need to call prepare() method here, or to escape the values ourselves, as the insert() method does this for us.

Comment: Probably just nitpicking, but  `insert` actually calls `prepare` internally but values are escaped using `mysql(i)_real_escape_string()`, no real prepared statements in WordPress.